# Removing from DOM content with function (which is attached to resize event) definition - results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

If I load external `html`:

```
$( "#result" ).load("test.html");
```

Where `test.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ftest(){
   console.log('ftest!');
}

$(document).ready(function(){

   $(window).bind('orientationchange', ftest);

   $(window).resize(ftest);

});
</script>
```

The question is: what would happen if I clear `#result` content (content of `test.html` will be removed). Would `ftest` function launch when resize happens but function which is attached to event is removed from `DOM` (thus ends up with error)?

Comment: Does `test.html` only have Javascript or HTML as well? And does your code already work?

Comment: `test.html` has only JS, but my final html would have links to external css, js and html code inside. Code in above form works.

Comment: Moreover according to my test `ftest` function is triggered even after removing function declaration from DOM. But I would like to ready experts' opinions about this (is this is browsers related matter or common)...

Comment: So, the answer is `NO` as once javascript is executed, it'd remain in the memory and emptying the container has no effect on it => [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701504/does-jquery-remove-clear-out-loaded-javascript-when-it-is-used-to-remove-a-sc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701504/does-jquery-remove-clear-out-loaded-javascript-when-it-is-used-to-remove-a-sc)

Comment: Ok, thx. So if I want to remove events attached via externally loaded html, I have to store reference to attached function (e.g. using data() from jQuery) and unbind it when content from `$( "#result" )` is removed?