# remove script after load in memory

Tags: javascript

I writing a plugin for browsers to remove some popup windows,i want to remove scripts with certain sources.they add onclick handler to document in external js files.so i want to remove scripts to stop their listeners.

I used this code to remove certain script from page:

```
function removeJS(filename){
 var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
 for (var i = tags.length-1; i >= 0; i--){ //search backwards within nodelist for matching elements to remove
  if (tags[i] && tags[i].getAttribute('src') != null && tags[i].getAttribute('src').indexOf(filename) != -1) {
   alert(tags[i].getAttribute('src'));
   tags[i].parentNode.removeChild(tags[i]); //remove element by calling parentNode.removeChild()

  }
 }
}
```

but script in remove file runs again because it is loaded in memory,
So how can i remove it from memory?
sincerely

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by removing the file?

Comment: see this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701504/does-jquery-remove-clear-out-loaded-javascript-when-it-is-used-to-remove-a-sc

Comment: i writing a plugin for browsers to remove some popup windows,i want to remove scripts with certain sources.they add onclick handler to document in external js files.so i want to remove scripts to stop there listeners.

Comment: You can't "remove a script", it has already been run and its effects are in place. The onclick handlers have no "memory" of which script has made them.  It's like trying to get rid of an old car by burning down the factory where it was made.

Comment: thanks for you helps