# Jquery and ajax page load in iframe function is not refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am facing an issue from past week without any solution.

I have a admin dashboard. Links are in left and when clicked on link the data loads in iframe in main content part.

Each data that loads in iframe has its own jquery function.

When everytime I click on link, the content changes but its jquery function is not removed.

For example, suppose I click on Create Invoice link. The form opens with its jquery function. Now again when I click on another link, this new page again opens with its own jquery function.
Now jquery of Invoice link does not allow second page jquery to work.
Because of this my pages are having conflict and function does not work as intended.

[dashboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtbyR.png)

Here is an example,

I am using [selectize.js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/)
I use it to provide search on select inputs.
Now I use this on one page and do not use on another page.

But it loads search function on all pages.

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#select").selectize({
    selectOnTab: true,
    openOnFocus: false
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my code to load each function in its own I frame.

```
<li class="item-group"><a id="ajaxid" href="{% url "createinvoice" %}" target="blank"><i class="material-icons">content_paste</i> Create Invoice</a></li>
          <li class="item-group"><a id="ajaxid" href="{% url "createdc" %}" target="blank"><i class="material-icons">content_paste</i> Create DC</a></li>
          <li class="item-group"><a id="ajaxid" href="{% url "createbos" %}" target="blank"><i class="material-icons">content_paste</i> Create BOS</a></li>

<script>
$("a[id=ajaxid]").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#magicid").load(target);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Consider adding a [mcve] and reading [ask].

Comment: First question and downvote. How do new members survive here? Its a valid question and there is no answer on google.

Comment: It's not about survival. It's about getting help. If you don't show code and present an example that's inspectable, nobody can help you. Therefore your question is not answerable.

Comment: My question is simple. How to kill jquery function after I reload another page through ajax without page refresh?

Comment: Find me an answer on Google and I will leave SO.

Comment: Sapna, nobody wants you to leave [so]. People here are trying to help. But your question does not have enough information to allow anyone to help. What do you mean by *"kill jquery function"*? Even though you seem to think it's a simple question, it's really unclear what you're asking. Until you fix that, expecting help is not realistic.

Comment: I have edited question, hope it helps now. Please remove downvotes, I may not be able to ask any question in future.

Comment: I am talking about this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701504/does-jquery-remove-clear-out-loaded-javascript-when-it-is-used-to-remove-a-sc

Answer (score 0):

Very difficult to understand the problem here. Try binding the event inside the document ready function like below:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$("#select").selectize({
selectOnTab: true,
openOnFocus: false
});

$("a[id=ajaxid]").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#magicid").html(target);

});
});
```

Also check this below url. Is that something you are trying to accomplish ?
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JprpBy#anon-login

Comment: I am referring to this issue.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701504/does-jquery-remove-clear-out-loaded-javascript-when-it-is-used-to-remove-a-sc

Answer (score -1):

Not enough details to pin point your exact issue if the problem is with the two functions and you are calling two different libraries they maybe conflicting. You might consider looking into setting them up to avoid conflicts. You can find some suggestions [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/%22here%22)

Comment: I am not using different libraries. May be I am not able to explain question. In nutshell, the issue is that I load data in a div #magicid. Everytime I load data in it, a jquery function also loads example selectize.js. Now when I load another content in this div, the earlier seletize.js does not get killed.

Comment: Talking about this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701504/does-jquery-remove-clear-out-loaded-javascript-when-it-is-used-to-remove-a-sc