# Loading page with AJAX and cancelling previous JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm creating a site where newly opened pages are loaded via AJAX. Each page uses a global.js and a .js just for that page. The problem is that when I load a new page the JavaScript of the previous page will still remain no matter what.

My AJAX:

```
$.post({
      url: "./some_url",
      dataType: 'html',
      data: { ajax: true },
      success: function(data) {
        //Here I would need a way to stop all the previous JavaScript
        $("#site").empty().append(data);
      }
});
```

Now I am looking for the best solution to this situation, because in some situations a page will have javascript running for x amount of time (by this I mean that a function will be looping doing some stuff) so I will have to add some if statement to check am I still on the correct page.

So the question is how should I solve it, is there a way to unload some javascript or maybe I should wrap all my functions into an object and null that object?

Also will the removed html elements EventListeners added via javascript be removed or will they actually stay somewhere until I manually remove them?

Comment: There is not enough information in your question. Please refer to the [ask] page and add a [mcve] to the question.

Answer (score 0):

well AJAX is for dealing with requests in background, just for not loading all page again so... your logic seems to be invalid.

Anyway you can delete scripts in-page or links to js sources:

```
<script id="mustBeRemoved">....</script>
```

or

Then with jQuery:

```
$("#mustBeRemoved").remove();
```

Or with plain JS:

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("mustBeRemoved"));
```

The fact now is when deleting it?
Just delete it when you don't need it anymore (before the AJAX request, for example, or just at the response, before loading something else).

**EDIT:**
Once a script is loaded, the objects and functions it defines are kept in memory. Removing a script element does not remove the objects it defines. This is in contrast to CSS files, where removing the element does remove the styles it defines. That's because the new styles can easily be reflowed.

However, if you have a file that defines "myFunction", then you add another script that redefines myFunction to something else, the new value will be kept. You can remove the old scripttag if you want to keep the DOM clean, but that's all removing it does.

The only **real way** to "clean up" functions that I can think of is to have a JS file that basically calls delete window.myFunction for every possible object and function your other script files may define. For obvious reasons, this is a really bad idea.

If you can analyse the js you need before coding it probably you can avoid this problems. If you project is enough developed for getting back, then the best way seems to delete the old script or link to the old script, and redeclare this functions to simply do nothing (or doing new different things).

Comment: I think you're getting it completely wrong. Firstly if you think my logic is invalid then you're kinda off with these days or maybe didn't really understand what I mean. Secondly, jQuery .remove() only removes the <script> tag not the JavaScript that has actually been ran so again you're either off or didn't fully understand me. But still thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Probably, if there's any js that causes issues when loading some content through Ajax request can be due by a bad defined JS (most probably) or getting too much content that isn't related with the content actually loaded so it runs different js files that override or missmatch something.

Comment: So that's why I'm thinking of putting every function into an object that I could null, but I am not sure is this the best solution. Also I'm not sure if that would stop functions that are currently running. Also let me add that a specific function will change some element content on the website that after the AJAX new page load that element won't exist anymore, because of the override.

Comment: Well, this is a difficult question to answer as I'll need some time and your full code. While you're not reloading the DOM the objects will remain till an override, same for functions. As you "can't access" RAM using JavaScript the best way for you is overriding functions as needed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701504/does-jquery-remove-clear-out-loaded-javascript-when-it-is-used-to-remove-a-sc
Just link answers instead of writing like you're the author :)

Comment: Same as searching before posting ;)
Hope it helps!

Comment: So I guess the best solution is creating an object that I could later null and put the functions inside that object. Anyway thanks for your answer @JoelBonetR :)